# Sending value through Jquery is showing null

Tags: jquery, json, asp.net-mvc-3

I am working on MVC3 and trying to pass values form view to controller using JQuery and JSON. The query is extracting values of checkboxes inside a grid. Following is the code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function DeleteCustomer() {
    if (confirm("Are you sure to delete records")) {
        $('#myGrid table tr').each(function () {
            if ($(this).find("input[id*='assignChkBx']").length > 0) {
                if ($(this).find("input[id*='assignChkBx']")[0].checked == true) {
                    //var CustID = $(this).find("input[id*='assignChkBx']").attr("CustomerID");
                    var id = $(this).find("input[id*='assignChkBx']").val();
                    var DTO = JSON.stringify(id);
                    alert(DTO); **//Showing right value**
                    var temp = $(this);
                    $.ajax({
                        url: "Customer/DeleteCustomeByID",
                        type: "POST",
                        dataType: "json",
                        data: DTO,
                        contentType: 'application/json',
                        success: function (data) {
                            alert('Success');
                        },
                        error: function (xhr, textStatus, err) {
                            alert('Error :(' + err);
                        }
                    });
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Above **'DTO'** is checkbox value which is giving right value.

Below is my html

```
        <input type="button"  id="btnDelete" value="Delete" title="Delete" onclick="DeleteCustomer()" style="color:steelblue"/>

<div id="myGrid" style="width:100%">

@*@Html.Partial("_grid", Model)*@
@{
    WebGrid grid = new WebGrid(Model, rowsPerPage: 15, ajaxUpdateContainerId: "myGrid");
}
@grid.GetHtml(
        //htmlAttributes: new { id = "myGrid1" }, 
    fillEmptyRows: false,
    alternatingRowStyle: "alternate-row",
    headerStyle: "grid-header",
    footerStyle: "grid-footer",
    mode: WebGridPagerModes.All,
    firstText: "<< First",
    previousText: "< Prev",
    nextText: "Next >",
    lastText: "Last >>",
    columns: new[] {
        grid.Column(header: "", format: @<text><input class="check-box" type="checkbox" id="assignChkBx" value="@item.CustomerID" /></text>),
        //grid.Column(header: "", format: @<text>@Html.CheckBox("assignChkBx") </text>),
        grid.Column("CustomerID", "CustomerID", canSort: true, style: "CustomerID"),
        grid.Column("CompanyName", "Company Name", canSort: true, style: "CompanyName"),
        grid.Column("ContactName", "Contact Name", canSort: true, style: "ContactName"),
        grid.Column("Address", "Address", canSort: false, style: "Address"),
        grid.Column("City", "City", canSort: true, style: "City"),

       grid.Column("", 
                    header: "Actions",
                    format: @<text>
                                @Html.ActionLink("Edit",   "Edit",   new { id=item.CustomerID} )
                                @Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id=item.CustomerID} )
                            </text>
        )

})
```

Problem occurs when I  passing the value from view to controller. Please view the following code:

```
        //Delete multiple Customers by CustomeByID
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult DeleteCustomeByID(string DTO)
    {
        try
        {
            // delete the record from ID 
            Customer customer = db.Customers.Find(DTO);
            db.Customers.Remove(customer);
            db.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");

            //return View(customer);
        }
        catch (DbEntityValidationException dbEx)
        {
            foreach (var validationErrors in dbEx.EntityValidationErrors)
            {
                foreach (var validationError in validationErrors.ValidationErrors)
                {
                    Trace.TraceInformation("Class: {0}, Property: {1}, Error: {2}",
                        validationErrors.Entry.Entity.GetType().FullName,
                        validationError.PropertyName,
                        validationError.ErrorMessage);
                }
            }

            throw new Exception();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw new Exception(ex.Message);
        }

    }
```

Here two errors have been occurring.

i. The variable DTO is shwing  'null'

ii. When '**db.Customers.Remove(customer);**' statement executes I am getting following error.

***Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: entity***

I can not understand why those errors are occurring. **Remove** statement is working perfectly when parameters are passing without JQuery.

I am using Northwing database.

Thanks

Comment: can you post exactly what the DTO string looks like, often times this is the problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function DeleteCustomer() {
if (confirm("Are you sure to delete records")) {
    $('#myGrid table tr').each(function () {
        if ($(this).find("input[id*='assignChkBx']").length > 0) {
            if ($(this).find("input[id*='assignChkBx']")[0].checked == true) {
                //var CustID = $(this).find("input[id*='assignChkBx']").attr("CustomerID");
                var id = $(this).find("input[id*='assignChkBx']").val();
                id="{'DTO':'+ id +'}" **//This is change**
                var DTO = JSON.stringify(id);
                alert(DTO); **//Showing right value**
                var temp = $(this);
                $.ajax({
                    url: "Customer/DeleteCustomeByID",
                    type: "POST",
                    dataType: "json",
                    data: DTO,
                    contentType: 'application/json',
                    success: function (data) {
                        alert('Success');
                    },
                    error: function (xhr, textStatus, err) {
                        alert('Error :(' + err);
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    });
}
```

}
Just check my code
id="{'DTO':'+ id +'}" **//This is change**

Comment: url: "Customer/DeleteCustomeByID/"+id, try this one.